# How to compare 2 files and remove non-existent lines?

Tags: java, file, compare, hashset

I'm trying to remove non-existing lines from file 1 compared to file 2

Example:

Input

file 1

```
text
example
word
```

file 2

```
example
word
```

Output

file 1

```
example
word
```

My code is totally the opposite: it eliminates all duplicate words in the 2 files.

My actual output is:

file 1

```
text
```

Code

```
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
Set<String> lines2 = new HashSet<String>(10000);
String line2;
while ((line2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines2.add(line);
}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(10000);
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
Set set3 = new HashSet(lines);  
set3.removeAll(lines2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the intersection between the two sets. Right now you are calculating the symmetrical difference between the sets.

```
 public static void main(String []args){

    Set<String> file1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> file2 = new HashSet<>();

    file1.add("text");
    file1.add("example");
    file1.add("word");

    file2.add("example");
    file2.add("word");

    Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<>(file1);
    intersection.retainAll(file2);

    System.out.println(intersection);
 }
```

Output:

```
[word, example]
```

Comment: @A.Mekki Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are almost there with your approach all you missing is another line of code were you call

```
lines.removeAll(set3);
```

then you have the set (lines) with the needed result.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you read in file 2 then file 1 and just removed the words in file2 from file1, leaving the one different word.
Here I wrote out the code, and commented. You needed to have a set that then removed that one word from the complete list. 
In my code I made a new set, just in case you want to rebuild the first set, and leave it as un-modified.

```
package scrapCompare;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class CompareLines {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //You create a set of words from file 1.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1"));
    Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(10000);
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    //You create a set of words from file 2.
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2"));
    Set<String> lines2 = new HashSet<String>(10000);
    String line2;
    while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
        lines2.add(line2);
    }

    //In your original code, you create a third set of words equal to file 1, and then delete all the words from file 2.
    //It isolates the one different word, but you stopped there.
    Set set3 = new HashSet(lines);  
    set3.removeAll(lines2);

    lines.removeAll(set3);
    //the answer set is made, in case you want to rebuild the lines set.
    Set <String> answer = lines;
    //iterator for printing to console.
    Iterator<String> itr = answer.iterator();
    //print the answer to console 
    while(itr.hasNext())
    System.out.println(itr.next());

    //close your readers
    reader.close();
    reader2.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RemoveLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "../file.txt";
        String file1 = "../file1.txt";
        String file2 = "../file2.txt";

        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        Set<String> lines2 = new HashSet<String>(10000);
        String line2;
        while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
            lines2.add(line2);
        }

        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        Set<String> lines1 = new HashSet<String>(10000);
        String line1;
        while ((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
            lines1.add(line1);
        }

        Set<String> outPut = lines1.stream().filter(l1 -> lines2.stream().anyMatch(l2 -> l2.equals(l1))).collect(Collectors.toSet());


        Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        Files.write(Paths.get(file), outPut, utf8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    }

}
```